# Why is my array being overwritten java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, encapsulation

I am still learning about encapsulation. I have a `GrammarList`, where every `Grammar` emcapsulated has an array `listRule` with all their setters & getters. as seen here:

```
public class Grammar {

private enum Type {Left, Right, NULL};
private String Nom;
private static Type type = null;
private static ArrayList<Rule> listRule;

public Grammar(String nom, Type type) {
    this.Nom = nom;
    this.type = type;
    this.listRule = new ArrayList<Rule>();
}
...
}
```

Now in my program, I notice that my array listRule (where are the rules associated with a grammar are added ) is being overwritten each time a new grammar is added. I have been able to identify that the error happens on the line `Grammar grammar = new Grammar(parametre[0], null);` which empties the content of listRule of all other grammars so listRule seems to be the same for every grammar. Is my array listRule created incorrectly or is my loop?

```
    try {
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] parametre = strLine.split(",");
            Grammar G = GrammarList.containsNom(parametre[0]);
            if (G == null) {
                Grammar grammar = new Grammar(parametre[0], null);
                grammarList.add(grammar);
                for (int i = 1; i < parametre.length; i++) {
                    SyntaxCheck check = new SyntaxCheck(parametre[i]);
                    if (check.isValid())
                        grammar.AddRule(check.Rule, check.Sens);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, for better help sooner post a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `listRule` field is `static`, which means every instance shares the same object.

Remove the `static` keyword:

```
private ArrayList<Rule> listRule; // not static
```